# __pillar___ empty in custom module

Tags: salt-stack

I write a simple custom module, and would like to access the pillar data.

I test it like this (file `salt/_modules/foo.py`):

```
def bar():
    assert 0, __pillar__
```

sls file `salt/tmp/test_pillar_in_custom_module.sls`:

```
{{ salt['foo.bar']() }}
```

And I execute it like this:

```
salt-ssh --log-leve=all foohost state.sls tmp.test_pillar_in_custom_module pillar='{systems: [foosys]}' 2> tmp/o
```

Relevant part of `tmp/o`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt/salt-call", line 27, in <module>
    salt_call()
  File "/var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt/pyall/salt/scripts.py", line 431, in salt_call
    client.run()
  File "/var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt/pyall/salt/cli/call.py", line 57, in run
    caller.run()
  File "/var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt/pyall/salt/cli/caller.py", line 138, in run
    ret = self.call()
  File "/var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt/pyall/salt/cli/caller.py", line 237, in call
    ret['return'] = self.minion.executors[fname](self.opts, data, func, args, kwargs)
  File "/var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt/pyall/salt/executors/direct_call.py", line 12, in execute
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/tmp/.root_dcdf8c_salt/running_data/var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/modules/foo.py", line 2, in bar
    assert 0, __pillar__
AssertionError: {}
```

But the dict `__pillar__` is empty.

I read the docs: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/modules/developing.html#pillar

> The `__pillar__` dictionary contains the pillar for the respective
>   minion.
>
> While `__pillar__` is defined for every module, it's only filled in for
>   some.

In my custom module it is empty.

Is there a way to access the pillar in a custom module?